# fopen() creation permission mode

Tags: c, fopen, file-permissions

According to the [OpenGroup](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/open.html), if open() is called with O_CREAT and the file does not already exist, it will be created with the file permission specified as the third argument in the function:

> the file shall be created; the user ID of the file shall be set to the
>   effective user ID of the process; the group ID of the file shall be
>   set to the group ID of the file's parent directory or to the effective
>   group ID of the process; and the access permission bits (see
>   ) of the file mode shall be set to the value of the third
>   argument taken as type mode_t

Is it possible to do something similar with fopen() so that I can set the permissions of a new file on creation, without having to chmod it afterward?

Comment: If you'll want various different permissions, it's easier just to use `chmod` directly. Otherwise `umask` for a default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `fopen(3)` man page:

> Any created files will have mode `S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH (0666)`, as modified by the process's umask value (see umask(2)).

So `umask(2)` is your friend.